# My Asus K40IN hangs after a ram upgrade was installed, how do I fix this?

Tags: memory, bios

From a 2GB RAM I upgraded the K40IN and added another ram to make it into 4GB. what happens is it hangs a lot. Especially right when I boot/startup the laptop. Would updating the resolve this problem, if it does how do I update the bios?

And where can I get the BIOS for the update?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is take out the new memory module and verify that the machine still works OK.

If it does then swap out the old memory for the new. This will tell you whether you've got a faulty memory module or not. If the machine fails in the same way, then you've probably got a faulty module. Get it replaced and repeat the process.

If the machine works OK with the new 2GB module then look into the BIOS.

**EDIT**

From your comment it looks like the memory module is OK.

Comment: It works okay withoout the new, even with the new...there are just times when it hangs at startup, if that happens i turn it off manualy and boot to safe mood. And then start it again until it doesnt hang...ill try doing that this weekend-swap it for a new one.

Comment: Does it hang equally often without the new ram stick? If not, then it sounds like the ram stick is faulty. (Or at least, it's a possibility).

Answer (score 0):

Updating BIOS drivers is unlikely to fix the problem.

That said, here you go: 
[Asus support page for the k40IN](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?model=K40IN&f_name=k40inas220.zip&SLanguage=en-us)

[k40IN product page](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=VB4TfUFszKKyzdR1)